# linux ll output interpretation

Tags: linux, ls

this is a regular output an ll command

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 something     root 4096 2008-11-04 16:58 something
```

I would like to ask if this output is like this,

```
crwxr-xr-x 2 something     root 4096 2008-11-04 16:58 something
```

what does the "c" mean?

Comment: should this be moved to SuperUser?  I personally just found this question very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from [OS X ls man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ls.1.html) :

```
       b     Block special file.
       c     Character special file.
       d     Directory.
       l     Symbolic link.
       s     Socket link.
       p     FIFO.
       -     Regular file.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `c` stands for character device. This is a special type of device, which, instead of operating on blocks, operates on characters (technically blocks of size 1).

Sadly, the `ls` man page on Linux does not say much about that. However, the [FreeBSD man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls) for ls does.

Nevertheless, this should have been asked on the super user stack exchange.

Comment: I know sorry but, this was an urgent situation and I couldn't find the answer. Thank you very much.